# How to unit test Angular routeChangeSuccess in directive link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Karma keeps throwing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalPath' of undefined` given a directive with the following in the `link` function:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('sidebar', ['$route', function ($route)
{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/sidebar.html',
    scope: {
      activeNav: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, curr, prev) {
        scope.activeNav = curr.$$route.originalPath || '/about';
      });
    }
}
```

and unit test:

```
describe('sidebar directive', function () {
  var $compile,
    $rootScope,
    scope,
    element;

  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
  beforeEach(module('my.templates')); // ng-html2js karma template loader

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));


  it('defaults to /about route', function() {
    element = $compile("<sidebar></sidebar>")(scope);
    var linkScope = element.children().scope();

    $rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess');
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(linkScope.activeNav).toBe('/about');
  });
});
```

When logging the `curr` route from within the link I get `Object{params: Object{}, pathParams: Object{}, locals: Object{}}`. I've tried passing a mock route to the broadcasted message but nothing changed. How would I get the expected (default) route to pass into the directive? Is this even the right way to go about tracking a route change within a link? My guess is that I'm just new to Jasmine and unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out how to trigger the route change using `$route.reload()`

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route), it:

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed. As a result of that, ngView creates new scope and reinstantiates the controller.

So adding that to my test 'reboots' the route, forcing routeChangeSuccess to emit and, once digested, passes into the `link`. Here's the updated block from the spec file with an added $location change to test other routes:

```
describe('sidebar directive', function () {
  var $compile,
    $rootScope,
    $route,
    $location,
    scope,
    element;

  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
  beforeEach(module('my.templates')); // ng-html2js karma template loader

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$route_, _$location_){
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $location = _$location_;
    $route = _$route_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile("<sidebar></sidebar>")(scope);
  }));


  it('defaults to /about route', function() {
    $route.reload();
    $rootScope.$digest();
    var linkScope = element.children().scope(); // Get directive's isolated scope
    expect(linkScope.activeNav).toBe('/about');
  });

  it('sets activeNave to correct route on change', function() {
    $location.path('/foo');
    $route.reload();
    $rootScope.$digest();
    var linkScope = element.children().scope();
    expect(linkScope.activeNav).toBe('/foo');
  });
});
```